# How do I apply a function to just one element of a Keyword list?

Tags: elixir

Say I've got a keyword list that looks like:

```
[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3...]
```

I want to return a keyword list that looks like:

```
[a: f(1), b: 2, c: 3...]
```

Where `f/1` is a function I've applied to the element `:a`.

The length or order of the list is not deterministic.

What's the nicest way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: The nicest way would probably be to use a different data structure. Maybe consider using a map?

Comment: “Applied to the element `:a`”—what if the keyword list has several `:a` keys? Should `f/1` be applied to all of them? To the first one?

Comment: @JustinWood `map` can not be used if a keyword list is supposed to have several `:a` keys.

Answer (score 1):

To apply to the first element:

```
iex(1)> [{key, value} | tail] = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
iex(2)> fun = fn(num) -> num + 1 end              
#Function<6.128620087/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(3)> [{key, fun.(value)} | tail]               
[a: 2, b: 2, c: 3]
```

If the order and length are not deterministic, I would suggest translating to a map first.

If the list is small, it's possible to loop through elements one by one and match on `:a` to run a function.

Comment: BTW converting to the map apparently **removes all `:a` keys but the first one**. If the goal is to apply `f/1` to all `:a` keys, one nevertheless should traverse the whole list. If we are chasing the first one, then probably `Enum.chunk_while/4` would do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Keyword.update!/3` or `Keyword.update/4`:

```
list = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
Keyword.update! list, :a, &(&1+1)
```

Comment: BTW this apparently **removes all `:a` keys but the first one**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Kernel.update_in/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/3) as well (apart from the Keyword.update! solution)

```
list = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
Kernel.update_in list, [:a], fn(value) -> value end
```

Where the `fn` part is up to you how you transform the value.

**EDIT**

IF there are multiple `:a` keys in the keyword list, then you can use [Enum.map/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) as:

```
list = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, a: 4]
Enum.map list, fn {:a, v} -> {:a, v+1}; {k,v} -> {k,v} end
```

Comment: Based on my understanding from OP's description there's only one `:a` key: "...applied to the element :a." I presume they would have used plural in case there's a need to address multiple `:a` keys.

Comment: One should not rely on the expectations of how the data will look like. If the data is fully under our control, we might apply `f/1` _while we were creating the list_. I dropped these comments for strangers who might visit this question in the future and blindly use any of already posted solutions. And everything will be fine until in a year the list gets another `:a` key—and everything eventually breaks.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Updated the answer, although without the OP's clarification this may seem to me as premature optimization.

Comment: You should care less about OP and more about future visitors :) SO is made to be a knowledge base not a “get me the answer” service.

Comment: I understand the sentiment and agree with it largely. Although if you are strict about this I'd wager 90% of the questions and answers would need updating for future proofing like this :)